Unable to do anything on any pen drive from my laptop(windows 11)
except read am unable to perform anything even if i am unable to format the pen drive not mine one only but any pen drive which are working fine on different systems is giving same issue on my system. for e.g. when i try to create a folder or a file.
enter image description here
then  after clicking continue i got another one
enter image description here
I tried through diskpart to remove readonly operations if exists and also to format but shows windows is unable to complete the format action. and right click -> properties -> security tab -> gives full control to user also to everyone, also from disk manager delete the driver and restart to reinstall them everything i did.

you might better ask this on superuser, since stackoverflow is for programming and programming environmental questions. Good look
